# Write a single SQL Query to show list of movies that have been rented and at the same time not rented by customers in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Movie Table has the following columns:

```
Movie (Movie_ID, Movie_Title)
```

Customer Table has the following columns:

```
Customer (Cus_No, Cus_FName, Cus_LName)
```

Rental Table has the following columns:

```
Rental (Rental_ID, Cus_No, Movie_ID)
```

Now this is the question:

By using a single SQL Query (in MS Access), List the names of all movies and for all movies list the names of all customers who have hired it. If a movie has never been hired then list it anyway. Sort the final result by movie name and customer last name.

This is how I approached

```
SELECT Movie_Title, Cus_LName, Cus_FName
FROM Movie, Customer, Rental
WHERE Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID AND NOT (Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID)
AND Customer.Cus_No = Rental.Cus_No AND NOT (Customer.Cus_No = Rental.Cus_No)
ORDER BY Movie_Title, Cus_LName;
```

But, I am getting blank result.

How would the SQL Query look like in MS Access for this question?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  This looks like homework.

Comment: SELECT Movie_Title, Cus_LName, Cus_FName
FROM Movie, Customer, Rental
WHERE Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID AND NOT (Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID)
AND Customer.Cus_No = Rental.Cus_No AND NOT (Customer.Cus_No = Rental.Cus_No)                                                                                             This is how I approached but I am getting blank result.

Comment: Could you edit your question, and add this information? Make sure to indent the SQL block with 4 spaces, so it renders as code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get no results is that your conditions are contradictory:

You have:

```
Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID AND NOT (Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID)
```

... but these two conditions can never be true at the same time, yet you require them to be with `AND`.

What you are really looking for is [outer joins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208894(v=office.12).aspx).

```
SELECT    Movie_Title, Cus_LName, Cus_FName 
FROM      (Movie
LEFT JOIN Rental ON Movie.Movie_ID = Rental.Movie_ID)
LEFT JOIN Customer ON Customer.Cus_No = Rental.Cus_No
ORDER BY  Movie_Title, Cus_LName
```

This way a Movie record will still be listed even if the condition in the first `ON` clause has no match with a Rental record. In that case the SQL engine will fill up the missing values for the customer name with `null`. That is exactly what the `LEFT JOIN` is for. With `WHERE` you would lose out on such Movie records.